# How to use an object with Vuetify v-select?

Tags: vuetify.js

Can I use an object for the `items` prop with Vuetify `v-select` ?

If yes, how to set the object key as `item-text` and object value as `item-value` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. But is easy, you convert the object to an array using the default text and value:

```
<v-select 
  v-model="selected"  
  :items="Object.keys(items_obj).map((key) => ({text:key, value:items_obj[key]}))" 
/>
```

May be better to create a computed property or a method, or even your custom component if you do this a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to use object in v-select

```
<template>
<v-select
      v-model="select"
      :items="items"
      item-text="state"
      item-value="abbr"
      label="Select"
      return-object
      single-line
    ></v-select>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    data () {
    return {
        select: { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
    items: [
      { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
      { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
      { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
      { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
      { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
    ],
  }
},
}
</script>
```

Visit this link to read more about it https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#custom-text-and-value

Comment: This isn't actually using an object, this is using an array still. This would work if you wanted to use an array of objects.